# How to set selenium to process the next url when the current one loads more than 30 seconds?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to know what to put into exception condition. I'm currently using the pass statement, but I'm not sure whether it does exactly what I want it to do. The reason why I want to implement this is because some webpages takes more than 30 seconds to load completely, like: taobao.com. My code is as followed:

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from time import sleep 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile() 
profile.add_extension(extension = '/Users/wayne/Desktop/fourthparty/extension/fourthparty.xpi') 

driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
def scan(cutoff): 
    with open('top-1m.csv', 'r') as f: 
        for num, url in enumerate(f): 
            if (num == 500): 
                return

            url = url.split(',')[1] 
            driver.get('http://www.' + url) 
            sleep(30) 

            try: 
                driver.set_page_load_timeout(30) 
            except TimeoutException: 
                pass

if __name__ == "__main__": 
    scan(500)
```

Comment: Could you tell me what you will do after the page is timeout? Continue testing or terminate the test?

Comment: Sorry I didn't clarify that point. I would like the driver the get the next url once the current one loads for more than 30 seconds.

Comment: I think Levi's answer can solve your problem.

Comment: Still, I don't know what to put under the exception. I mean, how should the program jump to the next line of the .csv file and read it? Can I increment the url variable like the num variable by url++? I guess not, right?

Comment: Could you show us some lines in the CSV file?

Comment: I completed the code by rewriting the crawling part.

Answer (score 0):

You do the `set_page_load_timeout` once, usually shortly after instantiating the driver. You should then wrap the `driver.get` in the try except, like so:

```
from __future__ import print_function

from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.add_extension(extension = '/Users/wayne/Desktop/fourthparty/extension/fourthparty.xpi')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)

def scan(cutoff):
    with open('top-1m.csv', 'r') as f:
        for num, url in enumerate(f):
            if (num == 500):
                return

            url = url.split(',')[1]
            try:
                driver.get('http://www.' + url)
            except TimeoutException:
                print("Caught and handled slow page timeout exception")

            # Do something here I guess?


if __name__ == "__main__":

scan(500)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the new program that gets the next url if the current one has loaded for more than 30 seconds. It may not look as a typical Python program since I'm used to Java.
    from selenium import webdriver
    from time import sleep
    from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
    import csv

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
profile.add_extension(extension = '/Users/wayne/Desktop/fourthparty-master/extension/fourthparty-jetpack.1.13.2.xpi')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)

with open('top-1m.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    fList = list(reader)

def crawl(cutoff):
    for i in range(0, cutoff):
        try:
            driver.set_page_load_timeout(30)
            getURL(i)
        except:
            pass

def getURL(num):
    url = 'http://www.' + fList[num][1]
    driver.get(url)
    sleep(30)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    crawl(10)
```